# How can I dynamically retrieved data attribute names from a table for each table rows in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ngtable

I'm using many ng-table in my app with for each a different number of columns and data like the example below:

```
tr.drillable(ng-repeat='data in $data')
   td(data-title="name", filter="{fullname:'text'}"){{ data.fullname }}
   td(data-title="email", filter="{email:'text'}") {{ data.email }}
   td(data-title="phone", filter="{phone:'text'}") {{ data.phone }}
   td(data-title="address", filter="{theMainAddress:'text'}") {{ data.theMainAddress }}
```

What I'm trying to get is the name of each filters attribute in an array
var attributes = [fullname,email,phone,theMainAddress].

Is there any easy way to do that?

I've tried few experiment but nothing close to the result needed.

Can anybody give me a lead please?

Comment: Look at the keys of a data object inside $data.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div *ngFor="let dataObject of data; let i = index">
        <div>{{dataObject.fullname}}</div>
    </div>
```

Loop through data.
Here stores would be an array filled with objects. You could also do this in tables